# Android+OkHttp Basic Authentication 401 Unauthorized issue

Tags: android, authentication, basic-authentication, okhttp

I'm trying to use OkHttp on Android to connect to an API that uses Basic Http authentication, and even though I appear to be doing everything right, I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error.

The API is configured a little strangely in that it apparently requires the username (Base64 encoded) to be included in the url; it will not accept a properly formatted "Authorization: Basic " header. So the request has to be formatted like this:

```
https://<username>:<password>@www.api.com/api/ver/1/method
```

Where "username" and "password" are the Base64 encoded username and password entered by the user.

When I take the URL being sent by OkHttp and try it directly with curl, it works. So I know that the username and password are correct, they are being encoded correctly, and the url is being constructed correctly. But when I try it in my app, I get a 401 Unauthorized error with a "Www-Authenticate" header. Which is exactly what it sends if I try it in Postman with the "Authorization" header instead of the username and password in the url.

Is it possible that OkHttp is trying to be smart here, and pulling the username and password out of the url and automatically generating an "Authorization" header before sending the request? If so, I'd like to stop it from doing that.

Comment: I would recommend you to use some proxy to see what you are sending exactly. i.e I use Charles proxy

Comment: It's a good idea, but Charles proxy doesn't seem to be intercepting the traffic from my Android emulator, so it's not showing me anything useful.

Comment: humm, weird... any request in your computer should be using Charles. This kind of issues are very difficult to solve without seeing what you are sending  in the http request :(

Comment: OK, well, I was able to use an Interceptor in OkHttp to look at the URL and headers being sent. Everything looks fine. I was even able to copy the URL directly from the Interceptor log, feed it into curl, and I got a valid response. But when it's being called in the app, I get a 401. This is insane; I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: I had a similar issue using my app and curl. The problem was that curl was using cookies from a previous session. Can you remove the cookies and then try again with curl? I did it from Chrome / Settings /

Comment: I didn't even realize curl stored cookies. How do I delete all curl cookies from the command line?

Comment: No idea from command line. I did it from Chrome. You can use any browser